# Django translation {% trans '...' %} works but {% blocktrans %} does not work

Tags: django

I am currently trying to translate my website and somehow I am not able to get `{% blocktrans %}` to work.

```
<html lang="en">
<p>
    {% blocktrans with USERNAME=worker.username MANAGER=manager.username%}
        LOGIN_INFORMATION_FOR_USER_HAVE_BEEN_RESET_BY_MANAGER
    {% endblocktrans %}
</p>

<p>{% trans 'YOUR_NEW_CREDENTIALS' %}:</p>
</html>
```

The `.po` file looks as follows

```
msgid "LOGIN_INFORMATION_FOR_USER_HAVE_BEEN_RESET_BY_MANAGER"
msgstr "The login information for %(USERNAME)s have been reset by %(MANAGER)s."

msgid "YOUR_NEW_CREDENTIALS"
msgstr "Your new credentials"
```

And all of this results in this:

[image]

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Do not use a new line, this results in extra spacing characters: write the block on a ssingle line without extra spacing.

Comment: Hi Willem thanks for your suggestion but unfortunately this didnt do the trick. Do you have any other idea ?

Comment: Okay I have played around a bit, when I remove the `%()s` from the `msgstr` and put everything in one line at least I get the following to be displayed: `The login information for USERNAME have been reset by MANAGER.`

Comment: How can I replace the variable names with their corresponding values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this issue by using the variable placeholder `%(USERNAME)s` in the `msgid`. Then, blocktrans worked as expected.